# CORS image loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, cors

I have an extension which creates a cross-origin iframe on the page.  The user can then select images on the page, and they are copied into the iframe.  The way I do this is by copying all the attributes on the image (class, style, src, etc), adding "crossorigin = 'anonymous'", and then creating the image, like so:

```
        //obj contains all of the DOM properties from the original image tag
        var src;
        if (obj.nodeType === 1 && obj.tagName) {
            if (obj.attributes) {
                //Check for cross-origin
                src = obj.attributes.src ? 'src' : (obj.attributes.href ? 'href' : null);
                if (src) {
                    obj.attributes[src] = obj.attributes[src] + '?dummy=232';
                    if (obj.attributes.crossorigin) { delete obj.attributes.crossorigin; }
                    node.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
                }
                for (var a in obj.attributes) {
                    node.setAttribute(a, obj.attributes[a]);
                }
            }
        }
```

However, I'm still getting the following error:

**Image from origin 'http://www.slate.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'ttp://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.**

For the record, [here is the article I'm using for testing at the moment](http://www.slate.com/articles/sports/fivering_circus/2014/02/olympics_viewers_guide_slate_s_comprehensive_look_at_what_to_watch_at_the.html) (I'm trying to copy the first image of the two skier girls).  Does that error just mean that Slate has blocked all Cross-Origin image loading server-side, and that I'm SOL in terms of loading that image in a different frame?

Comment: What happens if you don't add the `crossorigin` attribute on the image tag?

Comment: @abraham The canvas gets tainted and you cannot export image data. Look it up in MDN.

AlexZ, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @pilau why are you assuming the author cares about canvas data export?

Comment: @abraham Ha! Silly me. That was what I was trying to tackle. Forget it :)

Comment: I don't care about cross-origin export, but sadly removing the crossorigin tag didn't help either.  I've accepted that this can't be done and gone a different route.